# Apache Flink: How does it handle the backpressure?

Tags: apache-flink, backpressure

For an operator, the input stream is faster than its output stream, so its input buffer will block the previous operator's output thread that transfers the data to this operator. Right?

Do the Flink and the Spark both handle the backpressure by blocking the thread? So what's the difference between them?

For the data source, it is continuously producing the data, what if its output thread is blocked? Would the buffer overflow?

Answer (score 7):

https://www.ververica.com/blog/how-flink-handles-backpressure

The article explains in great detail how backpressure is handled implicitly within flink